# Create common log file using two different log files as input

Tags: elastic-stack

I have a requirement where i have to visualize data using two log files from two different sources , one is haproxy logs and other is nginx logs. I am trying to ELK stack but i am not able to parse the two different log files in a common format using logstash.

Below is the format for haproxy log:

```
**Feb 22 21:17:32** ap haproxy[1235]: 10.172.80.45:32071 10.31.33.34:44541 10.31.33.34:32772 13.127.229.72:443 [22/Feb/2020:21:17:32.006] this_machine~ backend_app/app_32772 40/0/5/1/**836** 200 701381 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 {cdn.net} {hitting} "GET **/ob/720/output00007.ts** HTTP/1.1"
```

Below is the Nginx Log:

```
183.87.179.64 - - [**24/Feb/2020:16:58:08** +0000] "GET **/felaapp/hd_images/apple.jpg** HTTP/1.1" 200 3414616 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0" **1.049** - .
```

I want the highlighted content and a extra filed to identify the source of data in below common format

```
"Date" "Time" "Content" "Responsetime in Milliseconds" "Source"
"24-02-2020" "16:58:08" "/felaapp/hd_images/apple.jpg" "836" "Nginx"
"22-02-2020" "21:17:32" "/ob/720/output00007.ts" "1.04" "Haproxy"
```

I am trying to get this done through logstash using gork and mutate plugin, but i am open to csv format also, but i will be needing the data in real time so the csv has to be updated on real time basis.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Both Nginx and Haproxy have a Filebeat module that can be used to convert the log to the ECS format. From there, you could query both the same way, and also use elastic SIEM features as a bonus.